# Independence and change of measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr F)$ be a finite probability space and $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\Omega$. Consider a sequence of random variable $\xi_n$ that are independent and identically distributed:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\mu\left(\{\xi_n=1\}\right)=p,~~ \forall n,\\
\mu\left(\{\xi_n=-1\}\right)=1-p,~~ \forall n,\\
\mu\left(\left\{\xi_n=\pm1\right\}\cap\left\{\xi_m=\pm1\right\} \right)=\mu\left(\left\{\xi_n=\pm1\right\}\right)\cdot\mu\left(\left\{\xi_m=\pm1\right\} \right),~\forall n\neq m 
\end{array}\right.
$$

Suppose I define a new measure by assigning

$$
\lambda\left(\{\xi_n=1\}\right)=p^{\prime},~~\lambda\left(\{\xi_n=-1\}\right)=1-p^{\prime},~~\forall n,
$$

what can I say on the independence or pairwise independence of $\xi_n$ according to $\lambda$ ? In other words, for which conditions it turns out that $\xi_n$ are independent according to $\lambda$ or

$$
\lambda\left(\left\{\xi_n=\pm1\right\}\cap\left\{\xi_m=\pm1\right\} \right)=\lambda\left(\left\{\xi_n=\pm1\right\}\right)\cdot\lambda\left(\left\{\xi_m=\pm1\right\} \right),~\forall n\neq m ?
$$

Comment: Your $\lambda$ is only defined on two sets. If $m\neq n$ then it is not defined on set $\{\xi_m=1\}$.

Comment: Sorry I meant for all $n$, I changed the post accordingly.

Comment: You wrote: "Let $\Omega$ be a finite probability space...". Do you mean $\Omega$ has finite cardinality?

Comment: Assigning 

$$
\lambda\left(\{\xi_n=1\}\right)=p^{\prime},~~\lambda\left(\{\xi_n=-1\}\right)=1-p^{\prime},~~\forall n,
$$

does NOT completely define $\lambda$.

Comment: Even with only two random variables, you may have that they are independent  for one probability measure, but not for another probablity measure.

Comment: Is that the definition of independence? I think that is pairwise independence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\Omega=\left\{ -1,1\right\} ^{2}$ equipped with $\sigma$-algebra
$\wp\left(\Omega\right)$ and probability measure $\mu$ prescribed
by:

$\left(1,1\right)\mapsto p^{2}$; $\left(-1,1\right),\left(1,-1\right)\mapsto\left(1-p\right)p$
and $\left(-1,-1\right)\mapsto\left(1-p\right)^{2}$.

Let $\xi_{1},\xi_{2}$
be the projections.

Then the conditions mentioned in your question are satisfied.

Let $\lambda$ be another probability measure prescribed by:

$\left(1,1\right)\mapsto p$; $\left(-1,1\right),\left(1,-1\right)\mapsto0$
and $\left(-1,-1\right)\mapsto1-p$.

Then the conditions are satisfied with *exception of the independence*.

So if the condition of independence is left out then the conditions do not determine $\lambda$.

Comment: Is that the definition of independence? I think that is pairwise independence

Comment: @BCLC If you are dealing with exactly $2$ random variables (as in my answer) then the concepts "independence" and "pairwise independence" coincide.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, drhab. I meant to ask you about how the OP defines independence

Comment: @BCLC The OP starts with saying that the $\xi_n$ are independent. Then pairwise independence is mentioned as a necessary condition for that. It is indeed *not* a sufficient condition, but the OP didn't claim that.

Comment: drhab, i mean for the latter part w/ the 'in other words'

Comment: @BCLC He was indeed a bit sloppy there. I am shrugging.

Comment: You know, we do have asterisks or something for things like that eg *shrugs* hahaha